# How to use Observer and Listener in MVC in Java

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

Can I use notifyObservers() in the model and the method update() in the view to upgrade the GUI? In other way can I use ActionListener (or I can implements my listener) to communicate between the view and the controller? It is correct? I've written some code but I haven't found the solution, because there are a lot of buttons to implements and I would avoid to put a lot of if to understand which button is been pressed. I make an example. In the map there are 30 buttons and three categories of buttons (10 that call a method, 10 another and so on). Each button pass different information to the method. Can I manage this situation avoiding a cascade of if in the class that must manage the pression of the buttons?

Comment: This is very broad. Break your problem down for us. Can you implement your desired behaviour for a single button only? If not then edit your question with just that code and we can have a look.

Comment: You can (not sure you should), but need to be careful the updates happen in the GUI thread, if the update to the model wasn't in the gui thread